# Gatsby : Cannot execute componentWillReceiveProps when running 'gatsby develop`

Tags: gatsby

Can anyone explain why when running `gatsby develop` the Child component’s lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps` is ignored and it is re-mounted with every new change - whereas when building the static version of the app, the Child's `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method is executed correctly.

See attached ‘dev’ and `build` gifs, or [checkout the source](https://jsfiddle.net/chrisbuttery/n5u2wwjg/30142/).

Dev

[image]

Build

[image: BUILD]

Comment: I think Gatsbay has this issue. On props update it's re-mount the child component.

Comment: I created a new Gatsby project and copy pasted your fiddle into it, and I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. It works as expected for me... My test was on `gatsby v1.9.223`.

Comment: @Nenu Thanks. I'll try that version. I'm currently using version `1.9.238`.

Comment: @DenimDemon Well it works for me even with the version `1.9.238`. I think your issue should come from something else.

Comment: @Nenu Yes you're correct. Thank you.
I created a fresh gatsby project and it works as expected.
Sorry to waste your time.
If you'd like to add your response as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DenimDemon glad to hear that it works for you too :). I wont add an answer as we didn't identified your issue. But thanks for the offer^^

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved by removing `gatsby-plugin-preact`>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nenu, I discovered that the issue is elsewhere. Using the example code in a fresh gatsby project worked as expected.